# Android Studio Throws an error if a user reaches the character limit

Tags: java, android-studio, maxlength, editview

I used the `maxLength` method. I want you to be notified "Limit characters here are 10 characters"
I know the user can't add characters anyway, but I still want to be notified.
**How do i get when the user is still trying to add characters to throw him an error?**

Comment: Could you add the code in question?

Comment: there is nothing to see. i just asked how to know when the user tring to add letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about an EditText view.
Which one do you use? The Android widget one or the Material one?

Because the Material TextField (https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields) has an easy to use character counter:

[image: Google Material docs]

---

If you then want to additionally show an error (e.g. with a [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts)) you can get the max length counter by calling `yourTextInputLayout.getCounterMaxLenght` and check it.